# Any way to see weapon stats?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-2

Is there any way to see the stats of a weapon besides the vague text description?

Mostly to see which weapon is the best.
Playing on console, so pc mods or hacks are not an option.

Comment: I could swear that you can see the stats in-game. Haven't actually played the game in years, though. Might be a button to toggle from the text to the stat bars or something like that.

Comment: @DCShannon Nope. not on colsone anyway

Comment: I thought there were detailed bars indicating weapon stats when you were in the weapon modding screen...go to your ship and manage equiptment and loadouts pretty sure it had a compare function as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you start here, you should be able to get the information you need:

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Assault_Rifles#Mass_Effect_2

Similar entries for the other weapons should be available.